# Angular - Update html attribute in root index.html

Tags: angular, angular7

I have following content in my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Halls Gate</title>
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.png">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Istok+Web" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to update dir and lang attribute in html element from a component `<html dir="ltr" lang="en">` based on the language selected.

Is there a way to go about this in Angular?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think, it can be changed simply...

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ih2drk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(document.querySelector('html'), 'lang', 'tr');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help. this is working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This will be a bad practice. You should use [Internationalization](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) instead. 
Internationalization is the process of designing and preparing your app to be usable in different languages. Localization is the process of translating your internationalized app into specific languages for particular locales.

Make your start with:

```
ng serve --configuration=your locale id
```

Comment: I am using https://github.com/ngx-translate/core with https://github.com/Greentube/localize-router and it is working well, I haven't used angular Internationalization, I will take a look at it.

Comment: Stock is always the best ;)

Comment: lol, let's say, no point reinventing the wheel, anyway, appreciate your help. Thank you. I am definitely going through what you suggested, just want to get a grip of it and really understand the difference.

Comment: Doing that ONLY does not change html tag's `lang` attribute, when your `<app-root></app-root>` is in the body of index.html. I feel like this answer is not close related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular-i18n and want to change locale based on build, you can do this

```
import {Component, Inject, LOCALE_ID} from '@angular/core';
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/common'; 
...
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document, @Inject(LOCALE_ID) locale: string) {
     this.document.documentElement.lang  = locale;
  }
  ...
}
```